# Creating duty roster (aka schedule, time table, etc...) using R

Tags: r, scheduling

Just being curious, having a feeling that creating a duty roster for a few people in a week seem to be a "human-only" task, I wonder if this can be automated? is there any package available in R for that? Thanks.

Comment: I'd consider it to be bespoke to each definition of a roster that it's more about just writing your own rather than anyone investing time building a package for something like this. Too many variables basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a whole branch a math that is devoted to these kinds of tasks: scheduling. Although these kinds of techniques are more often applied to for example scheduling a large steel mill, it could also be applied to much smaller problems. Take a look at some links I found using `Rseek.org`:

- http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e17/help/12/03/8488.html